# How do you toggle overwrite in Wordpad? (The insert key pastes, so doesn't help)

Tags: windows, wordpad

I was typing in Wordpad and it started overwriting.

If I press <kbd>Insert</kbd>/<kbd>Ins</kbd>, then it pastes, so that's not it.

How do I turn overwrite off?

Added: I got it now but I'm gonna include some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**top keyboard**

On the keyboard that has only a INS/Num lock key (the top pic).   That keyboard has only one insert key - that one.  I don't see any purpose to the num lock key on that one as it has no number pad. But, the num lock won't/doesn't affect whether or not that insert key toggles overwrite.    I mistakenly thought insert was reached with shift. But no, insert while written at the top of the key, is not reached with shift.

On any computer, hitting Shift+Insert, in wordpad, will paste.  The solution was to not hit shift. I didn't know that at the time and so at the time, I similarly, I didn't realise I was doing shift+insert at the time. (I thought I was hitting shift to reach insert).

Hitting the Fn key with that key would toggle Num Lock.  And num lock only affects the insert key on the number pad, of which that key is not it.

**bottom keyboard**
On the keyboard in the bottom picture, there are two insert keys. One in the top row and one in the number pad. The one in the top row, is like the key on the keyboard in the top picture.  (except that Fn + that key does print screen rather than num lock).  The other insert key on that keyboard, is in the number pad, and num lock affects that one.

so, both insert keys are fine, just don't hold shift.

and obviously if an insert key is printing 0s then it's a num lock issue but that wasn't the case with me.

So if a key has a white symbol and a blue symbol, then no shift key is used even if one symbol is above the other. If it has as I can see.. two white symbols and one blue, and the white symbols are one above the other, then of course, use shift for the white symbols.

Answer (score 3):

The insert key does toggle overwrite in Wordpad.

Are you sure you aren't using the Ins key on the numeric keypad with NumLock on?  That would stop it.

Comment: One one computer, LaptopA where my issue is, it's a laptop with a cramped keyboard, MSI laptop, it has no number pad, it has a button with num lock and Ins - ins is accessed with Shift. I don't know what use num lock is without a keypad on this laptop! but Whether num lock is on or off,ins just pastes. and at the moment text is overwriting.On my other laptop, laptopB(not really one with the issue), it has insert and ins on number pad.Ins either types 0 or toggles overwrite.The Insert key pastes.So I guess I need the number pad ins/insert and I don't have it on laptopA. The other insert pastes.

Comment: top row, second from the right,  is a button with num lk and ins on it, and ins is reached with shift.  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2UZ98ceyJhI/Tey5qrj4LEI/AAAAAAAAB0Y/2i4-uHx3lC4/s1600/MSI_U135_DX_purple_4-300x202.jpg  (and of course my laptop is not purple)

Comment: thus far I find if I type a bunch of characters, go in the middle of them, then experiment wildly hitting ins/numlk, shift and fn, and typing,  doing that over and over again, then within a minute or so I hit on the right combo and it toggles overwrite! but no idea what that combo is yet.

Comment: My error was hitting shift   (+1 for your first line!)

Comment: and of course it wasn't  'num lock on' causing an issue, because if it was then it'd have printed 0s.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, it worked just to to press Ins NumLK and Backspace at the same time without 'shift'. It toggeles overwrite on and off in wordpad. The issue comes by accidently hitting them both.